# Como fazer no código acender onde esta em laranjado

Tags: css

[image: Fazer acender onde está em laranja]

não sei como e nem como procurar para fazer esse esquema de deixar em laranja quando eu passo o mouse.

Comment: Seria o efeito hover ? http://jsfiddle.net/filadown/m55xqrkb/

Comment: Exatamente amigo, é com :hover só não sei de que maneira terei que fazer pra acender essas trilhas.

Comment: Você tem o código destas trilhas ? poste na sua pergunta, ajuda bastante na elaboração de uma resposta!

Comment: Tem várias maneiras de se fazer isso. Pode ser com SVG, apenas com DIVs bem posicionadas, com imagem, entre outros métodos. Só depende de como são estruturadas as trilhas. Tem algo pronto pra servir de referência? E o melhor é que dá pra fazer tranquilamente sem JavaScript (e muito menos jQuery, que o pessoal abusa).

Comment: Pois bem amigos eu ainda preciso fazer essa trilhazinha mas não sei como se alguém poder me ajudar agradeço de coração.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer este efeito com o `hover`.

**Exemplo:**

```css
li {
  width: 70px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hover</li>
  <li>Focus</li>
  <li>Active</li>
</ul>
```